# include? method returns false but it should be true

Tags: ruby

Can someone please explain me why the following code returns false? It's Ruby.

```
[
  "86f4914a-d5b4-4034-a3ff-4e0c5fdb6bbd",
  "0b9bae30-6df1-4569-96c4-fecbc1db6509",
  "cf2b2787-ea29-4604-92d3-890b7004e38e"
].include?("86f4914a-d5b4-4034-a3ff-4e0C5fdb6bbd")
#=> false
```

I expected it to be true but it returned false. I don't understand why..

Comment: Why are you using a version of Ruby on Rails that has not been maintained in years and has open, unpatched security vulnerabilities? What does this have to do with Ruby on Rails? Have you tried updating Ruby on Rails to a version that is still supported?

Answer (score 5):

There is a lower/upper case issue.

- In your array you have: `"86f4914a-d5b4-4034-a3ff-4e0c5fdb6bbd"`
- In the `include?` you have: `"86f4914a-d5b4-4034-a3ff-4e0C5fdb6bbd"`

The error is here: `4e0c5` vs `4e0C5`